# building json from array using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

This is a noob question, I am trying to build a json with an array 
something like this

```
   $a['info']=array("firstname"=>"-","lastname"=>"-","age"=>"-");
   echo json_encode($a);
```

This is the results I get from the above

```
info: {
  firstname: "-",
  lastname: "-",
  age: "-"
 }
```

But I want it as

```
info: [
  {
   firstname: "-",
   lastname: "-",
   age: "-"
  }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: Wrap it into another `[]` array I guess ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put your info content into an array (that is actually numerically indexed)

This will work:

```
$a['info'] = array();
$a['info'][] = array("firstname"=>"-","lastname"=>"-","age"=>"-");
echo json_encode($a);
```

and it will allow you to add more items to the list.

```
$a['info'] = array();
$a['info'][] = array("firstname"=>"1","lastname"=>"1","age"=>"1");
$a['info'][] = array("firstname"=>"2","lastname"=>"2","age"=>"2");
$a['info'][] = array("firstname"=>"3","lastname"=>"3","age"=>"3");
echo json_encode($a);
```

each empty `[]` pushes another item into the array.

Comment: Or just in short: `$a['info'] = [["firstname" => "-", "lastname" => "-", "age" => "-"]];`

Comment: Awesome - feel free to upvote (or mark as the answer) so that others can find the applicable answer)

Comment: @scunliffe  this is syntactically wrong definition- `$a['info'] = array();`

Comment: @spiderman I'm not sure I follow.  Do you take issue with the `$a['info']` part or the `array();` part?

Comment: My bad! I was telling there's issue with `$a['info']` part. I tried in an online php terminal when I got confused , and it reported a illegal String offset warning. But now to ensure I am correct, I tried with http://phpfiddle.org/ , and it says your syntax is correct. I haven't tried doing like this so far . Apologies. You're good

Comment: Thanks, no worries - just wanted to correct it if there was something messed up. - thanks!